# Update Query Two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update one table from another using and update and join.

I would like to update the **book** table `category` field (most recent insert) with the **category** table `id` field - where am I going wrong?

```
UPDATE book 
    JOIN category 
    SET book.category = category.id
    WHERE id = $query->insert_id
```

Currently the data is sent to both tables separately, nothing is updated. I need to update a single row only, I made this mistake earlier and updated every row!

I am very new to pho/mysql so any help and direction is welcome.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to suggestion from @Benni I am able to update the row, however it updates not with the most recent insert but with the first row in my db. See below

My category table

```
id   cat_name
2    Childrens 
3    Science
1    Maths
23   Comedy
```

My book table

```
id   category    title
1    2           a title here
2    2           a title here
3    1           a title here
4    Comedy      a title here
```

Both the `ID` fields are primary keys.

When I run the update my book table updates to 2 = Childrens, and not 23 = Comedy like it should.

My last `INSERT`

```
$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `book` (title,category,author,isbn,subtitle) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$query->bind_param('sssis',       
        $title,
        $category,
        $author,
        $isbn,
        $subtitle
        );
$query->execute();
```

Comment: You probably know the ID of the category you want to put your book into. Just put it into the `INSERT` query you use to create the book.

Comment: Show us more code. It is not clear what was your last `INSERT` and what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement should look like below. First you are missing `JOIN ON` condition and second, move the extra condition from `WHERE` to `JOIN ON` condition.

```
UPDATE book b 
    JOIN category c ON b.some_common_column = c.some_common_column 
    AND c.id = $query->insert_id
    SET b.category = c.id
```

Comment: Can you share your table structure for both book and category along with few sample data. Posted code in answer should work just fine. `some_common_column` is a common column between the tables on which you can relate them or join them. Does both the table have any relationship between them?

Answer (score -1):

You are going wring in the `ON` Part of your join. Try this:

```
UPDATE book, category 
SET book.category = category.id
WHERE book.id = $query->insert_id
```

Or (with `JOIN` Syntax):

```
UPDATE book 
JOIN category 
ON book.id = $query->insert_id
SET book.category = category.id
```

Comment: No idea. This works, however it updated every row in my table! I only wanted to update the most recent row.

Comment: By what colum would you identify "the most recent row"?